# Installed SUPEE 8788 patch not recognizing Magereport

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, supee-8788

I have installed the SUPEE 8788 patch without using SSH. I am using following link

[How to install SUPEE-8788 without SSH](https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh)

But magereport not recognized this patch.

[image]

My magento version is 1.9.2.4

Comment: I tried the link and nothinh is worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the following files:

```
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

Comment: Already deleted those files

Comment: Please cross verify that all files are placed or Upgrade to latest magetno 1934, it will have all patches inbuilt

Comment: I have placed all the files. Currently I didn't have the right to upgrade the version

Comment: it will work for sure...unless we see the website and code it is difficult to find out the error Abraham

Comment: Totally 80 files are in that package. I have uploaded all these files again. And remove the 3 swf files.

Comment: total 83 files and 2 swf files

Comment: I think the other 3 files are the txt files in the root. Also in the files-to-delete.txt  tells that 3 swf files need to delete

Comment: oh ok Arbraham, did you remove cache and session once

Comment: Yes,I already did it. Now I am checking with server cache.

Answer (score 1):

> Magereport checks for the following static assets that should have been removed:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

> It also checks for the following files that have been modified:

```
/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js should contain "fustyFlowFactory"
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css should contain "background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"
```